# Recycler View image issues and headaches

Tags: android, firebase, android-recyclerview

I have a layout issue with my recipe app, the image shows up in the recycler view when i'm looking at Android Studio's layout
but not when i run the app, in the app the image is simply blank also the image in that's showing in the layout is different than the one
i uploaded to FireBase, i wonder why the image is blank could there be a way to show the image from FireBase instead of showing the one
from drawable?, and also when i run the app the intent won't find the activity, could anyone give me some insight?.

Error:

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.recipeapp, PID: 12376
    android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity found to handle Intent { act=class com.example.recipeapp.DetailActivity (has extras) }
        at android.app.Instrumentation.checkStartActivityResult(Instrumentation.java:2051)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1709)
        at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:5192)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentActivity.startActivityForResult(FragmentActivity.java:676)
        at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:5150)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentActivity.startActivityForResult(FragmentActivity.java:663)
        at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:5521)
        at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:5489)
        at com.example.recipeapp.MyAdapter$1.onClick(MyAdapter.java:59)
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:7125)
        at android.view.View.performClickInternal(View.java:7102)
        at android.view.View.access$3500(View.java:801)
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:27336)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:883)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:100)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7356)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:492)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:930)
```

Activity_Detail.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".DetailActivity">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:id="@+id/ivImage2"
        android:src="@drawable/feijoada"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        android:contentDescription="@string/todo" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:padding="20dp"
        android:text="@string/description_feijoada"
        android:textSize="19sp"
        android:id="@+id/txtDescription"
        />

</LinearLayout>
```

DetailActivity:

```
package com.example.recipeapp;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import com.bumptech.glide.Glide;

public class DetailActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    TextView foodDescription;
    ImageView foodImage;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_detail);

        foodDescription = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtDescription);
        foodImage = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.ivImage2);

        Bundle mBundle = getIntent().getExtras();

        if (mBundle != null) {

            foodDescription.setText(mBundle.getString("Description"));
            foodImage.setImageResource(mBundle.getInt("Image"));

            Glide.with(this)
            .load(mBundle.getString("Image"))
            .into(foodImage);
        }
    }
}
```

Upload_Recipe activity

```
package com.example.recipeapp;

import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.annotation.Nullable;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnCompleteListener;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnFailureListener;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnSuccessListener;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.Task;
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;
import com.google.firebase.storage.FirebaseStorage;
import com.google.firebase.storage.StorageReference;
import com.google.firebase.storage.UploadTask;

import java.text.DateFormat;
import java.util.Calendar;

public class Upload_Recipe extends AppCompatActivity {

    ImageView recipeImage;
    Uri uri;
    EditText txt_name, txt_description, txt_price;
    String imageUrl;
    Object progressDialog;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_upload__recipe);

        recipeImage = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.iv_foodImage);
        txt_name = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txt_recipe_name);
        txt_description = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.text_description);
        txt_price = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.text_price);


    }

    public void btnSelectImage(View view) {

        Intent photoPicker = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK);
        photoPicker.setType("image/*");
        startActivityForResult(photoPicker, 1);

    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {

            uri = data.getData();
            recipeImage.setImageURI(uri);

        } else Toast.makeText(this, "Você não selecionou uma imagem", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    public void uploadImage() {

        StorageReference storageReference = FirebaseStorage.getInstance()
                .getReference()
                .child("RecipeImage")
                .child(uri.getLastPathSegment());

        storageReference.putFile(uri).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {

                Task<Uri> uriTask = taskSnapshot.getStorage().getDownloadUrl();
                while (!uriTask.isComplete()) ;
                Uri urlImage = uriTask.getResult();
                if (urlImage != null) {
                    imageUrl = urlImage.toString();
                }
                uploadRecipe();
            }
        }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
            @Override
            public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
            }
        });
    }

    public void btnUploadRecipe(View view) {

        uploadImage();

    }
    public void uploadRecipe() {

        final ProgressDialog progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
        progressDialog.setMessage("Enviando Receita...");
        progressDialog.show();
        progressDialog.dismiss();
        finish();

        FoodData foodData = new FoodData(txt_name.getText().toString()
                , txt_description.getText().toString(), txt_price.getText().toString()
                , imageUrl);

        String myCurrentDateTime = DateFormat.getDateTimeInstance()
                .format(Calendar.getInstance().getTime());

        FirebaseDatabase.getInstance()
                .getReference("Recipe")
                .child(myCurrentDateTime).setValue(foodData).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
            @Override
            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {

                if (task.isSuccessful()) {

                    Toast.makeText(Upload_Recipe.this, "Receita Enviada", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    finish();

                }

            }
        }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
            @Override
            public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                Toast.makeText(Upload_Recipe.this, "Falha ao Enviar", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                progressDialog.dismiss();
            }
        });
    }

    private void ProgressDialog(Object progressDialog) {
        this.progressDialog = progressDialog;
        ProgressDialog(progressDialog);
    }
}
```

Comment: from where's you are sending the data into `DetailActivity`

Comment: I'm sending the data from Upload_Recipe activity.

Comment: Have you declared `DetailActivity` in your `AndroidManifest.xml` ?

Comment: You didn't respond anything yet..

Comment: Yes it's in my manifest the activity even loads when i run the app but the intent doesn't recognize the activity.

Answer (score 0):

You are receiving the data from you **DetailActivity**

```
    Bundle mBundle = getIntent().getExtras();

    if (mBundle != null) {

        foodDescription.setText(mBundle.getString("Description"));
        foodImage.setImageResource(mBundle.getInt("Image"));

        Glide.with(this)
        .load(mBundle.getString("Image"))
        .into(foodImage);
    }
```

But you not sending any data from your **Upload_Recipe activity**

You can use this method to send the data.

1) Create a new bundle.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, DetailActivity.class);
Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
bundle.putString(key, value);
intent.putExtras(bundle);
```

2) Use the `putExtra();` method of the intent.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this,DetailActivity.class);
intent.putExtra(key,value);
startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: Cannot resolve methods getIntent, foodDescription, foodImage and startActivity, i tried to create the bundle in my onclick but it can't resolve anything.

Comment: The bundle can't resolve anything no matter where i create it, i even tried to create it in FoodData but the same thing happens.